# Querying SQLite Tree structure

Tags: sqlite, tree

I have a a database of tables like this:

`tree{id,name,parent}`
`content{id,content,parent}`

The `tree` table contains a tree-like structure where if parent is 0 it's the top level element and if it's different, it's the id of the parent from the same table.

The `content` table has a `parent`column which is an id from `tree` table.

What I want is to get is the whole chain of parent-children elements when given an ID for content.

I don't think this is the best structure for the tables and I think I can change this.

What's your take on this, please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, I'd recommend using `parent = NULL` rather than zero to indicate a root node, that would allow `tree` to have a foreign key on `parent` which references `id`; referential integrity is useful.

Then you could include a [materialized path](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=tree%20materialized%20path%20%5Bsql%5D&submit=search) from the root node to the current node in each row. The materialized path would be a string column that represents the path from a root node to the current node; for your purposes you'd want to use a fixed-width format for each node in the path, then you could ASCIIbetically sort on the paths to pull records out in tree-order (as in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797720/sorting-tree-with-a-materialized-path/2797724#2797724)).

Suppose you thought 99999 would be enough to cover all your nodes. Then you might have a string path like this:

```
'00001000110002300042'
```

That would represent the ID sequence `[1, 11, 23, 42]` so the node's parent would be 42, the grandparent 23, and so on up to the root of 1. To get the whole branch from a node to the root: grab the path, split it into pieces to get the IDs, and pull out all the nodes at once while sorting on the materialized path to get them out in the right order.

This approach also makes it easy to extract whole subtrees at once: just build the path prefix that matches your desired subtree and do a `path LIKE 'pfx%' ORDER BY path, id` to pull out the whole subtree with one pass. Also, most databases will use an index for a LIKE expression that is rooted at the beginning (i.e. `LIKE 'X%'` for some `X`) so these sorts of queries can be pretty quick. You can also compute the depth of a node with a simple string length and division computation.

You need to do a little bit of extra work to build the materialized paths but not much and they make a lot of tree operations nice and simple while maintaining the advantages of a natural representation of a tree.

Comment: materialized paths are great for querying - especially under queries but slower on writes.  If the tree is dynamic, write intensive, light on reads and not that deep, then simple id, parent recursive might be better.  It's highly dependent on the access patterns.  But often, a materialized paths column is good

Comment: @bryanmac: Everything depends on access patterns :) I usually work with PostgreSQL so recursive CTEs or materialized paths implemented with arrays and triggers usually do the trick.

Comment: Thank you, mu. [extra chars because it's too short]

Comment: A materialized path would also seem to be a poor choice if the tree is very deep.

Comment: @Michael If your trees are very deep (and very wide) then SQLite probably isn't the best data store to use. There are, of course, trade-offs with any approach.

Comment: @muistooshort yes performance is terrible (seems to be O[n]) but of course the tradeoff is that there don't seem to be any inexpensive/free encryption modules out there for things like UnSQL.

Comment: @Michael Do you have an index on the path? Some databases can use indexes for some anchored LIKE queries, I don't know if SQLite is one of them.

Comment: @muistooshort yeah, id and parent are both integers, one is the primary key and the other is indexed.

Comment: @Michael But your materialized path would be a string and that's the source of your problem, no?

Comment: @muistooshort ah sorry, i misunderstood.  the recursive trigger approach is O[n].  a materialized path would take too much space.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively you can use a [recursive common table expression](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html)