# help on threaded category Hierarchy with mysql

Tags: mysql, database-design

[image]

```
GID    name                     parent_GID     status
1      HQ                                      0 # 0 means its a category
2      Blog                     1              x # x some administration stuff
3      Feedback & Support       1              x
5      Service                                 0
6      Web                      5              x
7      Advertising              6              x
8      Others                   5              x
```

**to be something like ( 3 level )**

```
HQ
    Blog
    Feedback & Support
Service
    Web
        Advertising
    Others
```

**what i have done so far**

```
SELECT * FROM groups WHERE status = 0 # get categories
```

prints

```
HQ
Services
```

so we can do something like

```
# fetch categories
# get the GIDs
# fetch with foreach GID
  HQ # with GID 1 so search if there is child 1
      # SELECT * FROM groups WHERE parent_GID = 1
      Blog
      Feedback & Support
  Service # with GID 5 so search if there is child 5
      # SELECT * FROM groups WHERE parent_GID = 5
      Web
      Others
```

*the problem above is its olny 2 level Hierarchy.*

**any suggestion to do a level 3 fetch all ?**

thanks!

Comment: Use a materialized path: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276119/querying-sqlite-tree-structure/7277073#7277073

Answer (score 1):

A previous answer of mine might prove a good starting point:

[Generating Depth based tree from Hierarchical Data in MySQL (no CTEs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291054/hierarchical-sql-problem/5291159#5291159)

Hint:

change the following statement

```
insert into hier select parent_cat_id, cat_id, v_depth from categories where cat_id = p_cat_id;
```

to

```
insert into hier select parent_cat_id, cat_id, v_depth from categories where parent_cat_id is null;
```

and forget about passing in a starting parent_cat_id !

Hope this helps :)