# how implement a folder, subfolder in a Database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, recursion, relational-database

I'm having a problem with logic programming, but I think that could be another solution much easier to do this in a SQL command, however, let's go to the problem.

I have a table in MySQL (InnoDb) like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `folder` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `folder_id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `name` VARCHAR(100) NULL ,
  `hidden` TINYINT(1)  NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
  INDEX `fk_folder_folder1` (`folder_id` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_folder_folder1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`folder_id` )
    REFERENCES `folder` (`id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

It seems like a pretty simple, but I want to list the folders, in a way that the subfolders of this folder will appear below it. Like in any file repository.

For example:
In the table:

```
id  name    folder_id
1   root    1
2   etc     1
3   dev     1
4   apache  2
5   php     2
6   mysql   2
7   hda     3
8   hda1    3
9   lib     1
```

I want to show it like this:

```
root
    etc
        apache
        php
        mysql
    dev
        hda
        hda1
    lib
```

The question is, have a way to do this by SQL command or in PHP?

I try make in PHP, and I don't see a way without a recursive function. But i haven't success.

**Solution:**
Because the MySQL doesn't accept the WITH clause, the recursive function in SQL is out of the box. Thanks guys.

```
SELECT c2.name
FROM folder c1 LEFT OUTER JOIN folder c2
ON c2.folder_id = c1.id WHERE c2.folder_id = 1  // the id of the parent folder
AND c2.id != c2.folder_id               // Remove the parent folder
ORDER BY c2.folder ASC
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sorting tree with a materialized path?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797720/sorting-tree-with-a-materialized-path)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you're in danger of implementing an [SQL anti pattern](http://media.pragprog.com/titles/bksqla/trees.pdf) called naive trees.
See the pdf of the book, it shows several good solutions.

Comment: This is only an anti-pattern with MySQL because it (still) does not support recursive queries. In other DBMS it's very efficient to deal with such a structure.

Comment: I read the PDF that was linked but did not see an alternative to using a tree.  If someone is going to crusade against an anti-pattern I think alternative solutions need to be proposed.  IN the meantime I will continue to use either Oracle's connect by, write a stored proc or a CTE.  And the very useful tree structure.

Comment: @Karl, In the end of the Chapter, have a recursive implementation for SQL using the WITH clause, but have some RDBMS that doesn't suport hierarchies
stored (see section 3.4).