# How to properly sort a materialized-path?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to sort in sql the following path:

| Path |
| --- |
| 11 |
| 14 |
| 14.5 |
| 2 |
| 23 |
| 3.6 |

to look like this:

| Path |
| --- |
| 2 |
| 3.6 |
| 11 |
| 14 |
| 14.5 |
| 23 |

Comment: Simply `ORDER BY path`?

Comment: Column path data type?

Comment: Guessing you are storing your numerical data as a `varchar`, *not* a numerical data type; that s the problem. Fix your data types, fix the problem.

Comment: SQL Server has the [hierarchyid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/hierarchyid-data-type-method-reference?view=sql-server-ver16) type for materialized paths, along with functions that can check and find parents, children etc. `hierarhcyid` can be ordered and indexed properly no matter who long the PK value is. To get a `varchar` to work correctly you'd have to force all key values to have the exact same width by padding them with 0s

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting tree with a materialized path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797720/sorting-tree-with-a-materialized-path)

Comment: How does the OP *"Buna, DIn Nou"* a `hierarchyid` @BogdanSahlean ? What does that mean?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning that's not a good duplicate. SQL Server already has a `hierarchyid` type that solves the problem. That question is about PostgreSQL and shows a workaround only

Comment: Then sort values from HierarchyID

Comment: Check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/hierarchical-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Sect Key Properties of hierarchyid

Comment: a<b means a omes before b, in a depth first traversal of the tree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct type for materialized paths and hierarchies in general is [hierarchyid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/hierarchyid-data-type-method-reference?view=sql-server-ver16), not `varchar`. To get consistent ordering and searching with a text type you'd have to ensure all key values have the exact same length by padding them, eg `000014`, `000014.000005`, etc.

`hierarchyid` is a binary type but allows converting from and to string representations. It can be sorted and indexed and there are built-in functions to determine parents, children, levels etc.

[This example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/hierarchical-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16#simple-example) from the documentation shows how easy it is to use such paths

Given this table

```
CREATE TABLE SimpleDemo  
(
    Level hierarchyid NOT NULL,  
    Location nvarchar(30) NOT NULL,  
    LocationType nvarchar(9) NULL
);
```

and data :

```
INSERT SimpleDemo  
    VALUES   
('/1/', 'Europe', 'Continent'),  
('/2/', 'South America', 'Continent'),  
('/1/1/', 'France', 'Country'),  
('/1/1/1/', 'Paris', 'City'),  
('/1/2/1/', 'Madrid', 'City'),  
('/1/2/', 'Spain', 'Country'),  
('/3/', 'Antarctica', 'Continent'),  
('/2/1/', 'Brazil', 'Country'),  
('/2/1/1/', 'Brasilia', 'City'),  
('/2/1/2/', 'Bahia', 'State'),  
('/2/1/2/1/', 'Salvador', 'City'),  
('/3/1/', 'McMurdo Station', 'City');
```

The rows can be orderd with a simple `ORDER BY`. In this case `Level` is the name of the `hierarchyid` column :

```
SELECT 
    CAST(Level AS nvarchar(100)) AS [Converted Level], 
    *   
FROM SimpleDemo ORDER BY Level;
```

The expression `CAST(Level AS nvarchar(100))` converts the `hierarchyid` path values to their text equivalent.

The examples in [Lesson 2: Create and Manage Data in a Hierarchical Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/lesson-2-creating-and-managing-data-in-a-hierarchical-table?view=sql-server-ver16) go into more detail, showing how to add nodes at any level, search for ancestors etc.

In the `EmployeeOrg` table the `OrgNode` field is the primary key.

```
CREATE TABLE HumanResources.EmployeeOrg  
(  
   OrgNode hierarchyid PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,  
   OrgLevel AS OrgNode.GetLevel(),  
   EmployeeID int UNIQUE NOT NULL,  
   EmpName varchar(20) NOT NULL,  
   Title varchar(20) NULL  
) ;
```

When we know the hierarhcyId of an existing employee, we can find all subordinates with the `IsDescendantOf` function:

```
DECLARE @CurrentEmployee hierarchyid  

SELECT @CurrentEmployee = OrgNode  
FROM HumanResources.EmployeeOrg  
WHERE EmployeeID = 46 ;  

SELECT *  
FROM HumanResources.EmployeeOrg  
WHERE OrgNode.IsDescendantOf(@CurrentEmployee ) = 1 ;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to use hierarchyid datatype, but when I try to cast it on the fly I'm getting the following error which doesn't make too much sense for me:
SqlHierarchyId.Parse failed because the input string '9.4' is not a valid string representation of a SqlHierarchyId node.

Comment: `9.4` isn't a valid hierarchyid literal (ie text value). The format shown in the docs is `/9/4/`. Instead of casting it on the fly, add a new `hierarchyid` field and use that. You can convert the old values with eg `UPDATE MyTable SET node='/' + REPLACE(Path,'.','/') + '/'` where `node` is the `hierarchyId field

Comment: Indeed you are right, I thought it would let me use my format as well but it seems like it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Using the window function [ROW_NUMBER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to generate an id ordered by path can do the trick :

```
with cte as (
  select row_number() over(order by path) as id, path
  from mytable 
)
select path
from cte
order by id
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/3wfB-YKL)